# React hooks can also use the navLink, Link, Navigator, useNavigator of react-router v6.x to jump

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

No matter which api I use to navigate, it doesn't take effect, or it reports an error or a blank page. Below is the configuration of my index.js and router.

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
// import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import 'lib-flexible'
import Router from './router/index';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

router.js:

```
import React, { useEffect, lazy } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import "../global.scss";
import NavWrapper from "../components/navs"
const AIPage = lazy(() => import("../pages/AI"))
const BridgePage = lazy(() => import("../pages/Bridge"))
const PipelinePage = lazy(() => import("../pages/Pipeline"))

const BasicRoute = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    // console.log(window.location.pathname)
    const AIThemes = {
      '--app-themeColor': 'linear-gradient(270deg, #64e6c0 0%, #687ff9 100%)',
      '--app-border-color': '1px solid #6880F98C',
      '--app-background': '#262335'
    }
    const PipeThemes = {
      '--app-themeColor': 'linear-gradient(270deg, #1B74D4 0%, #25BC90 100%)',
      '--app-border-color': '1px solid #25BC90',
      '--app-background': '#262335'
    }
    const declaration = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style

    if (window.location.pathname === "/pipeline") {
      for (let key in PipeThemes) {
        declaration.setProperty(key, PipeThemes[key])
      }
    } else if (window.location.pathname === "/" || window.location.pathname === "/ai") {
      for (let key in AIThemes) {
        declaration.setProperty(key, AIThemes[key])
      }
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [])

  return (
    <Router>
      <NavWrapper />
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/pipeline" element={<PipelinePage />} />
        <Route exact path="/AI" element={<AIPage />} />
        <Route exact path="/bridge" element={<BridgePage />} />
        <Route exact path="/" element={<AIPage />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  )
};

export default BasicRoute;
```

package.json

```
"react": "^18.1.0",
"react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
```

After the configuration is complete, I have no problem entering the address in the address bar to access, only using the router to navigate has problems.

1. Using `Navlink` and `Link`

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Link, useNavigate, Navigate, BrowserRouter as Router, NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import styles from "./index.scss";

import aiGray from '@/assets/images/aiGray.png';
import bridgeGray from '@/assets/images/bridgeGray.png';
import caeGray from '@/assets/images/caeGray.png';
import pipeGray from '@/assets/images/pipeGray.png';
import { LinkOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';

const ActiveTheme = ({ themeName }) => {
   /**
  * String- themeName 当前主题名，传入值需与allTheme中匹配项的key相同，用以删除切换项
  */
   const navigate = useNavigate()

   const allTheme = [
      {
         icon: aiGray,
         link: '/AI',
         disabled: false,
         key: 'AI'
      },
      {
         icon: pipeGray,
         link: '/Pipeline',
         disabled: false,
         key: 'Pipeline'
      },
      {
         icon: bridgeGray,
         link: '/',
         disabled: true,
         key: 'bridge'
      },
      {
         icon: caeGray,
         link: '/',
         disabled: true,
         key: 'cae'
      }
   ]
   const [allThemeList, setAllThemeList] = useState(allTheme)

   // useEffect(() => {
   //    allTheme.forEach((item, ind) => {
   //       if (item.key === themeName) {
   //          allTheme.splice(ind, 1)
   //       }
   //    })
   //    setAllThemeList(allTheme)
   //    // eslint-disable-next-line
   // }, [themeName])

   const linkTo = (item) => {
      console.log(9999999999999)
      // --disable-ipc-flooding-protection
      navigate(item.link)
   }
   return (
      <div className={styles.routerInner}>
         {
            allThemeList.map((item, ind) => {
               return (
                  <NavLink to='/Pipeline' end>
                     <div key={item.key} className={styles.themeIcon} >
                        <img src={item.icon} alt="" />
                     </div>
                  </NavLink>

               )
            })
         }
      </div>
   )
}

export default ActiveTheme;
```

The page navigates but it is a blank page, the error is as follows：
"A component suspended while responding to synchronous input."

[image]

2. Using `Navigate`

```
<Navigate to='/Pipeline' end>
  <div key={item.key} className={styles.themeIcon} >
    <img src={item.icon} alt="" />
  </div>
</Navigate>
```

The page reports an error and falls into an infinite loop:

Maximum update depth exceeded.

[image]

I don't know where I trigger the `useState` infinite loop. How should I change the dependencies?

3. Usi `useNavigate`

```
const navigate = useNavigate()

return (
  <div className={styles.routerInner}>
    {allThemeList.map((item, ind) => {
      return (
        <div key={item.key} className={styles.themeIcon} onClick={navigate(item.link)}>
          <img src={item.icon} alt="" />
        </div>
      )
    })}
  </div>
)
```

The page does not report an error but gives a warning:
`"router.ts:11 You should call navigate() in a React.useEffect(), not when your component is first rendered"'.

[image]

Comment: The `Navigate` component unconditionally navigates, so if you are unconditionally rendering it the UI will render loop. The `navigate` function is being immediately invoked, so the UI similarly render loops. The `Link` should probably be what you want to use, but it's unclear where `ActiveTheme` rendering any link is being rendered. Please edit your post to include the relevant code you are trying to use as a [mcve].

Comment: There is a navigation bar in my page, click the button to expand the navigation bar, you can jump：

Comment: ActiveTheme is like a normal component reference

Comment: It's fairly obvious `ActiveTheme` is a React component, but that wasn't what I was driving at. Where is `ActiveTheme` being rendered for the link it's rendering to do anything? What is the `Navbar` component rendering? `ActiveTheme` renders links to `'/Pipeline'`. You're rendering a route on `"/pipeline"`. Paths are case insensitive so this *shouldn't* be an issue, and so I'm thinking the issue is elsewhere. Please include a [mcve] so it's clear to us where there is an issue in your code.